# Return all fields, Group by And Aggregate functions in lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have such a table as shown below

[image]

I need to group each record by LifePluseCaseId column,
and each group must be selected by Min distance and Min Duration
And return All of the fields.

I have tried this:

```
      var query = db.ApplicantCenterDistance.GroupBy(s => s.LifeplusCaseId)
                    .Select(s => new {
                        Id = s.Key,
                        MinDistance = s.Min(m => m.Distance),
                        Duration = s.Min(m => m.Duration)
                    }).ToList();
```

But i don't know how to get all fields in Select statement and what the role of key is.
Is s.Key equals to s.LifeplusCaseId?

Comment: Not directly answer to your question, but from my experience, running 2 separate LINQ queries is usually the best way in your case. It simplifies both the query as well as lower the data transfer between app and database although you may have to aggregate the data yourselves on server side.

Comment: `Is s.Key equals to s.LifeplusCaseId` yes, since you `GroupBy(s => s.LifeplusCaseId)`, `s.Key` is the `LifeplusCaseId` value.

Answer (score 0):

From the above queries, each group will have multiple `ApplicantCenterDistance`s record (in theory) because... well it's a group. If you really want to get all the items in each group as well, you can do like this (pseudo-code):

```
    var productByCategory = await db.Products
        .GroupBy(q => q.CategoryId)
        .Select(q => new {
            CategoryId = q.Key,
            // Here q is also acting as a list of products with the same `CategoryId`
            Products = q,
            // Or if you only want some specific fields
            ProductCustoms = q.Select(p => new {
                Name = p.Name,
                Color = p.Color,
                // All fields you want
            })
        }).ToListAsync(); // Do whatever you want with the result
```

Now it makes much more sense right? The `productByCategory` is a list of groups, each group has the key (`CategoryId`), and has a list of products that has that matching `CategoryId`.

Comment: I did this ``` var query = db.ApplicantCenterDistance.GroupBy(s => s.LifeplusCaseId)
                    .Select(s => new {
                        Id = s.Key,      
                        MinDistance = s.Min(m => m.Distance),
                        Duration = s.Min(m => m.Duration),
                        items=s,
                    }).Where(x=>x.MinDistance!=" ").ToList(); ``` but this error happen 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression '

Comment: Likely due to LINQ not able to translate a complicated GroupBy query. That's why it's better just do a simple GroupBy, get the Ids and do a second query that get the information you need and aggregate the data yourselves.